AWS S3 Policy to enable Bucket 'Actions'
I've must have looked at 50 articles to try and work this out but I just haven't found what I need. I have an AWS Account with 16 Buckets and all of them have the actions disabled as per the screenshot. Just wondering if there's a specific policy that enables these?
I'm part of the Admin group in IAM but AWS is very much outside my knowledge base :(


Those options are applied to Objects, not Buckets. What are you actually wanting to accomplish?
